# C# Relection addeventhandler : create Delegate fail cannot bind to the target method

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I have tried to add event from external dll file and i got argumentexception "Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type".

I tried to search the solution but they do not work with my code.

This is code in dll file.

```
public class StartProcess
{
     public StartProcess(){}

     public delegate void MSTStepInformEventHandler(object sender, MSTStepInformEventArg e);
     public event MSTStepInformEventHandler StepInformed;

     protected virtual void OnStepInformed(MSTStepInformEventArg e) 
     {
          if (this.StepInformed != null)
          {
               this.StepInformed(this, e);
          }
     }

     public void Start()
     {
          this.OnStepInformed(new MSTStepInformEventArg() { Info = DateTime.Now.toString()});
     }

public class MSTStepInformEventArg : EventArgs
{
    public MSTStepInformEventArg() { }
    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

And the below is reflection code.

```
class Test
{
    void HandleEvent(object sender, MainDLL.MSTStepInformEventArg e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HandleEvent called " + e.Info);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFrom("StartProcess.dll");

        Type classEx = ass.GetType("StartProcess.StartProcess");

        Test test = new Test();

        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(classEx);

        MethodInfo method = typeof(Test).GetMethod("HandleEvent", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        EventInfo eventInfo = classEx.GetEvent("StepInformed");

        Type type = eventInfo.EventHandlerType;

        Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(type, test, method); // Exception throw is here -----

        eventInfo.AddEventHandler(obj, handler);

        classEx.InvokeMember("Start", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, null);
    }
}
```

Please help...

Comment: Can you further simplify the code by deleting everything that is not required to reproduce?

Comment: I see that `StartProcess` class is inside `StartProcess` namespace, while in the `HandleEvent` method the type of the second parameter seems to be inside `MainDLL` namespace... is it correct? Did you define two types called `MSTStepInformEventArg` into two different namespaces?

Comment: Thanks so much to il-vic, my project has some problem about structure. I checked again, after put MSTStepInformEventArg into same namespace with StartProcess, my program works.